# JPQL & EclipseLink Concat

Tags: jpa, null, eclipselink, jpql, concatenation

When I am concatenating fields in `em.CreateQuery concat` returns NULL, cause one of my fields can have NULL. I want check for NULL as in Native MSSQL ISNULL(field,'somthing') function.

MyQuery is.

```
entManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW " + ThumbNail.class.getName() + "(p.id,p.thumbnail,p.thumbNailModifiedDate, CONCAT(p.firstName,' ',p.lastName,' ',p.middleName)) FROM Person p").setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true").getResultList();
```

Tried this one too

```
entManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW " + ThumbNail.class.getName() + "(p.id,p.thumbnail,p.thumbNailModifiedDate, CONCAT(FUNC('ISNULL',p.firstName,''),' ',FUNC('ISNULL',p.lastName,''),' ',FUNC('ISNULL',p.middleName,'')) FROM Person p").setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true").getResultList();
```

And it didn't work

Comment: If you are using a native function you could use a native query -> `entManager.createNativeQuery("Native SQL");` Eclipselink and the JPA in general handle nulls pretty well so I have not seen your issue, but if there's a good reason for it native queries are easy if not portable.

Comment: Thanx for reply. But I couldnt do it with native query caouse p.thumbnail is my Resource class. I have tried it with native Query. here it is. Copied it from log and changed to: entManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t0.ID , t1.ID,t0.THUMB_NAIL_ID, t1.CREATION_DATE, t1.FROM_MODULE, t1.CHANGE_DATE, t1.RESOURCE_BYTE, t1.DIGEST, t1.RESOURCE_TYPE, t0.MODIFIED_DATE, ISNULL(t0.FIRST_NAME,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(t0.LAST_NAME,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(t0.MIDDLE_NAME,'')  FROM INTERDIR_PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN INTERDIR_RESOURCES t1 ON (t1.ID = t0.THUMB_NAIL_ID)",ThumbNail.class).getResultList();
      Rised error.

Comment: Func was added to Eclipselink 2.1, so isn't usable in EL 2.0.1 you mentioned below.  It is replaced by FUNCTION in EclipseLink 2.4 for the JPA 2.1 spec: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Support_for_Native_Database_Functions#FUNC

Comment: **Can there be conflicts with other queries when migrating to later version of EclipseLink?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
But not with JPQL functions.

I just added new constructor to my pojo object and filled it with JPQL then concated there  with checkig for null. Thanx guys for answers.

Answer (score 3):

JPQL supports the coalesce function, which returns the first of its non-null arguments. So you could use

```
CONCAT(coalesce(p.firstName, ''), 
       ' ', 
       coalesce(p.lastName, ''),
       ' ',
       coalesce(p.middleName, ''))
```

I would put the middle name in the middle, rather than putting it at the end, though.

Comment: Seems JPA doestn support nested JPQL function usage. EclipseLink Version 2.0.1 , GlassFish V3

Comment: posting the exception and trying a later version of EclipseLink within glassfish. https://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/updating_eclipselink_bundles_in_glassfish

Answer (score 1):

modifying the jpa query is a mess...

just add a notNull method:

```
private String notNull(String input){ if (input != null) { return input.trim(); } return ""; }
```

and put this on every (String) setter on your Entity-Class

```
setFirstName(String name) { this.name = notNull(name) }
```

so all your "nulls" get "" and the jpa works

**BUT: then for db-nulls you get String="", so be aware..**